# Get comment id of the individual comments in comment list when modifying comment posted using comment text filter

Tags: comments, comment-form

I am trying to modify the comment displayed in the comment list and for that i am using the following code:

```
add_filter( 'comment_text', 'modify_comment');
function modify_comment( $text ){
wp_enqueue_script('cmt-player', plugins_url( 'js/cmt-player.js',__FILE__ ), array( 'jquery' ), '', true );
$comment_id = get_comment_ID();
$file_url = get_comment_meta($comment_id, 'record_file', true );
$site_parameters = array(
            'file_url' => $file_url,
            'plugin_url' => plugins_url(),
            'theme_directory' => get_template_directory_uri(),
            'comment_id' => $comment_id,
        ); 
wp_localize_script( 'cmt-player', 'wpvr_cmtvar', $site_parameters );
require( 'lib/cmtplayer-interface.php' );
}
```

But i am not able to get the comment id for a particular comment in the comment list, it is getting the comment id for the new comment only..

Any help would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `comment_text` filter passes the comment as one of its params:

`echo apply_filters( 'comment_text', $comment_text, $comment, $args );`

So you don't need to call `get_comment_ID()`, you can just access the ID from the `$comment` object.

Change:

`add_filter( 'comment_text', 'modify_comment');`

to:

`add_filter( 'comment_text', 'modify_comment', 0, 3 );`

And then:

```
function modify_comment( $comment_text, $comment, $args ){
    wp_enqueue_script( 'cmt-player', plugins_url( 'js/cmt-player.js',__FILE__ ), array( 'jquery' ), '', true );
    $comment_id = absint( $comment->comment_ID );
    $file_url = get_comment_meta( $comment_id, 'record_file', true );
    $site_parameters = array(
        'file_url'        => $file_url,
        'plugin_url'      => plugins_url(),
        'theme_directory' => get_template_directory_uri(),
        'comment_id'      => $comment_id,
    ); 
    wp_localize_script( 'cmt-player', 'wpvr_cmtvar', $site_parameters );
    require( 'lib/cmtplayer-interface.php' );
}
```